# GitHub Pages - Url Rewrite Support

Tags: github, github-pages

I have setup a GitHub page for a site I am working on, following the steps laid out here (https://pages.github.com/)

The site I have setup is currently hosted under IIS and makes use of the URL Rewrite module.

Is there an equivalent module or similar that I could use to rewrite certain URL requests within my application?

Comment: You may be interested in discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/408).

Answer (score 11):

For security reasons, Github pages doesn't allow server configuration files, so, no url rewriting.

But you can use html redirection with the help of [jekyll-redirect-from](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from).

This is how [github pages advises to redirect](https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages/).

Comment: **Then how is https://contentful.github.io/gallery-app-react/gallery/54O5P32wmcY0wiAY0ewA2e become NOT a _"Page not found"_?** https://github.com/contentful/gallery-app-react/issues/7#issue-483385870

Answer (score 10):

For Github Pages, just copy `index.html` and renaming it to `404.html` will work.

Reference:

- https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/8106429

Comment: I will "just work", but! a 404 (error) status will be returned to the client. Google search indexing ignores 404 pages (i.e. pages with an error). So although it will seem to "work" for the end user, it will be unfriendly for indexing on search engines, and your content will not be indexed.