# Visiting any URL except the landing page will re-direct to 404

Tags: github-pages

I have deployed my React.tsx project to Github Pages and it has successfully been deployed. You can visit the site on the initial view and re-direct yourself throughout the application routes, but when trying to initially visiting any other URL except the landing page you get re-directed to a 404(file not found) page.
[image]

**Issue**: If you visit any other URL initially except the landing-page you get re-directed to a 404.
If you click on 'Contact' you will get re-directed to the contact-page, but if you try to initially visiting that page(reloading) you will get re-directed to a 404. Meaning you can only visit the website with the URL to the landing page.

How can this properly be configurated so that any URL of the application can be visited initially?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub Pages - Url Rewrite Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390425/github-pages-url-rewrite-support)

Comment: Thank you @majkrzak, but I have seem to solved this issue by using HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter.